# Is it possible to override default style of ListBox validation in themes.xaml

Tags: wpf, validation, listbox, styles, default

I tried to change the default style for ListBox validation in my themes.xaml file but don't know how.
I hope can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `Themes.xaml` to override a default `Style` in WPF. You can do it quite simply using an ordinary `Style` in any `Resources` section:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <!-- Your Style Setters here -->
</Style>
```

Comment: But how can you override the validation style, so when you can't validate, it gives a red corner around it, but i want something else on every listbox. for example orange

Comment: I had to add this one, and remove te overridedefaultstyle because ijust wanted to do this and not the complete style: <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorTemplate}"/>